# What is the equavalent of mean of squared for random vectors?

Tags: maximum-likelihood

Given $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\sigma^2 + (\mathbb{E}[X])^2$ what is the equavalent for this when x is a random vector $\boldsymbol{x}$?

Trying to find what $\frac{\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{e}^T \boldsymbol{e} |\boldsymbol{X}]}{n}$

Where $e = \boldsymbol{Y} - \boldsymbol{X}\hat{b}$ and $Y \sim N(\boldsymbol{Xb}, \sigma^2 \boldsymbol{I})$

and $\hat{b} = \boldsymbol{X}(\boldsymbol{X}^T\boldsymbol{X})^{-1}\boldsymbol{X}^T \big(\sum_{i=1}^m Y_i \big)$

$\hat{b}$ is the MLE estimate.

$\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{\boldsymbol{e}^T \boldsymbol{e}}{n}$ is also the MLE estimate.

Comment: Do you mean $e^Te$ or $ee^T$?

Comment: no it is $e^Te$. Its the MLE estimate for variance for gaussian dist.

Comment: Hint: $e^Te$ is a scalar.

Comment: yes. $\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{e^Te}{n}$

Comment: You might want to reconsider if what you want to find really is $\frac{\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{e}^T \boldsymbol{e} |\boldsymbol{X}]}{n}$. Anyway, you're not doing anything with the expectation of a random vector. You are taking the expectation of the scalar quantity $e^Te$. Also, is this a homework problem or part of a class? If so, please add the `self-study` tag and read its wiki.

Comment: Its an expectation of a random scalar but it depends on random vectors. It is the MLE estimate of the variance. To check the unbiasedness need to take the expectation of it. Yes, $\frac{\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{e}^T \boldsymbol{e} |\boldsymbol{X}]}{n}$ is what is actually trying to be achieved not something else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104139/discussion-between-dave-and-john-karasev).

Answer (score 0):

With $X$ being a random column vector:

$$E[X \cdot X^T] = Cov[X] + E[X]\cdot (E[X])^T$$

Comment: I need $E[e^Te] not E[ee^T]$

Comment: What is $e$? Do you mind editing your question and the comment?